# Counting weeks in Tableau (starting in specific month)

Tags: tableau-api

I need to count number of weeks in a fiscal year starting with Oct 1. My fiscal year goes from Oct 1st to September 30th.

When I apply:

[image: Tableau screen shot to clarify]
    ATTR(datepart('week',[Generation Date]))

It counts the weeks, but it starts in January. My data properties and default properties are set to October.

Comment: How does using datepart() count the number of weeks? Shouldn't you be using datediff() instead?

Comment: @SamM I can, but I am trying to achieve a different purpose which I hope my edit to the question helps clarify what I am trying to do. I posted a screen shot of my tableau book in my question.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using inbuild week function you can create your own week number by just calculating date difference from fiscal year starting and then dividing by 7 then just take the next possible integer to get your week.
Let me know if you need exact formula

Comment: I appreciate the calculated field. I updated my question with a screen shot to help clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You should filter the dates by adding conditions using `IF` in a calculated field. In your case something like this if your fiscal year is fixed from Oct 1st to September 30th:

Write the following Formula in a Calculated field:

```
IF ([Generation Date] >= #01-10-2017#) AND [Generation Date] <= #30-09-2018#)
THEN [Generation Date]
END
```

Now use this calculated field the way you were using it before:

```
ATTR(DATEPART('week',[Calculated field]))
```

Comment: I appreciate the calculated field. I updated my question with a screen shot to help clarify.